# Detect an enumerate object in python

Tags: python, enumerate

If I have a list

```
L = range(10)
```

I can match it as a list using

```
isinstance(L, list)
```

However, if I want to enumerate it

```
M = enumerate(L)
```

It now becomes an enumerate object, which doesn't match as a list, and enumerate isn't a standard python object which I can match using isinstance.

What's the most elegant way to match an enumerate object?

Comment: More importantly, why are you trying to do that?

Comment: You guys are right, I don't know how I overlooked that. I was making a progress bar to wrap around processing a list, and I had an assert statement in there to check if it was a list - when the list was an enumerate object, it was breaking my assert.

Answer (score 2):

Why it's not a standard python object? you can use `isinstance(M, enumerate)` to check:

```
In [128]: e
Out[128]: <enumerate at 0x6933b70>

In [129]: type(e)
Out[129]: enumerate

In [130]: isinstance(e, enumerate)
Out[130]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Supplying `enumerate` as the second argument to `isinstance` should work fine:

```
isinstance(M, enumerate)
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> M = enumerate(range(10))
>>> M
<enumerate object at 0x020B7EB8>
>>> isinstance(M, enumerate)
True
>>>
```

And here is what the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) say*:

> isinstance(object, classinfo)
>
> **Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a > (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.** If
>   object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns
>   false. If classinfo is not a class (type object), it may be a tuple of
>   type objects, or may recursively contain other such tuples (other
>   sequence types are not accepted). If classinfo is not a type or tuple
>   of types and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.

---

*I added the bold.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see *why* you would want to do this, you can simply match the type:

```
>>> enumerate
<type 'enumerate'>
>>> isinstance(enumerate(range(10)),enumerate)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though what you really want to do is test to see if you can iterate over your type with a `for` loop. The way to do this is to test for a method called `__iter__`:

```
if hasattr(l, '__iter__'):
    # do something with the iterable
```

Or, you could use the standard library:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
if isinstance(l, Iterable):
    # do something with the iterable
```

This approach will work perfectly for lists, `enumerate`, tuples, and any custom object which is iterable